# JQuery .get not working on my page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I dont understand why this code doesnt work :

```
$( "#remove" ).click(function() {
    var getcontent = $("#noticeid").val();
        $.get("admincp.php", { removeid : getcontent } ,function(){
        });
});
```

Heres the html textbox :

```
<td><input class='form-control' style='position:absolute;left:500%;' type='text'  name='noticeid' value='$editid'></td>
```

And the button

```
<input type='button' id='remove' value='remove' class='btn btn-danger'>
```

And heres the PHP (on the same page):

```
if($_GET['removeid']){
        $removeid = $_GET['removeid'];
        $querydelete = "DELETE FROM `$dbtable`.`Notices` WHERE `NoticeID` = $removeid";
        mysqli_query($conn,$querydelete);
}
```

This worked with just simple PHP and HTML so it must be something to do with the script. Sorry if its  a really simple mistake but I cant seem to fix it.
**Edit:**

I was putting the input in a if clause that wasnt working so I fixed that but it still doesnt work, here is the new HTML code ($info7 = notice id ):

```
<input id='noticeid' class='form-control' style='position:absolute;left:500%;' type='text'  name='myname' value='$info7'>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Nope, none on google chrome.

Comment: #noticeid wont work because you are not reffering to the Id of the element. So nothing will change. You will need to do something like this `$("[name=noticeid]").val("")` if you want to clear the value. Or if you dont want to change your js code you need to add an id attribute to your element.

Comment: Another thing. Use google chromes developer tools. At the top where the tabs are use network to determine if the request is ever even sent to the server

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a dom element by ID, but only `name` is set in your html:

```
<td><input class='form-control' style='position:absolute;left:500%;' type='text'  name='noticeid' value='$editid'></td>
```

You should add id, e.g.:

```
<td><input id='noticeid' class='form-control' style='position:absolute;left:500%;' type='text' name='noticeid' value='$editid'></td>
```

And then you will be able to successfully do:

```
var getcontent = $("#noticeid").val();
```

Comment: Or you could use `$('[name="noticeid"]').val()` without having to change the markup.

Comment: Are you echoing your html through php? If it's outside `<? .. ?>` block, you should do something like `value='<?= $info7 ?>'` instead...

Comment: Its inside the PHP block, the whole HTML is echo'd with a script. To show that it works : http://i.imgur.com/oSOXdGc.png.

Comment: I know why, its because they are all ID'd noticeid so it doesnt know what to do I guess ? I cant think of a way to id them differently and then get that specific id in jquery unless i make a script for every single one =/

Comment: Yes, ID should be unique. If you have more than 1 similar input fields, you can get the dom elements using class selector, and then iterate the results to apply desired processing to each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve

```
$("#noticeid").val();
```

But there is no element with this `Id` in the `DOM`. Please add `id` attribute.

```
<input class='form-control' id="noticeId" style='position:absolute;left:500%;' type='text'  name="noticeid" value='$editid'>
```

If you don't want to add `id` then you can do like this

```
var getContent=$("input[name='noticeId']").val();
```

else

```
var getcontent=document.getElementByTagName("noticeId").value;
```

else

```
var getcontent=document.querySelector("input[name='noticeId']").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the value by name as you **don't have an id** in your `input type`

```
$( "#remove" ).click(function() {
    var getcontent = $("input[name='noticeid']").val();
        $.get("admincp.php", { removeid : getcontent } ,function(){
        });
});
```